# Android: BigPictureStyle of notification not working in android nougat

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Issue 1: Not able to change the color of the logo or background of logo from grey for push notifications.

Issue 2: Not able to display bitmap images in notification using BigPictureStyle.

All this problem is occuring in Android Nougat. I tried searching the solution for it but didn't seem to get any solution from stackoverflow or other blog. Tried using setColor() too, but it didn't work either. 
The icon is white and has transparent background too.

BigPictureStyle worked on emulator of API level 19.

```
    private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                        notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.logo);
        int icon = R.mipmap.icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

       Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),"default")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setWhen(when)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(bitmap).setSummaryText(messageBody))
               .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Comment: You've tagged the post with `firebase`.  Is `sendNotification()` called from `onMessageReceived()` of your  `FirebaseMessagingService`?

Comment: @BobSnyder yes it is!